# How can I communicate the state of a data area's pristine state to my scope?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
    <div data-ng-controller="AdminGridContentController" >
        <ng-include src="'/Content/app/admin/partials/grid-content-base.html'"></ng-include>
        <ng-include src="'/Content/app/admin/partials/table-content.html'"></ng-include>
    </div>
```

My table include looks like this:

```
<div ng-form name="page">
    {{ page.$pristine }}
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" class="form table" >
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>

            </tr>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="row in grid.data">
                <td>{{ row.contentId }}</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="row.title" /></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is to put a button on my grid-content-base that is enabled when the data on the table becomes dirty.  I know I can check the state of that data with {{ page.$pristine }} but how can I communicate that back to the grid-content-base.html?

Note that I did try to put everything inside the "ng-form name=page" but there's a problem. On the grid-content-base I have an input select. As soon as I do a select then it makes the page show as dirty.

So I still just want to set something globally when page.$pristine becomes true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always an option to do `$rootScope.$broadcast` and send a message from the table page. This can he handled in the grid page.

Something like this in table controller

```
$scope.$watch('page.$pristine',function(newValue) {
    $rootScope.broadcast("formUpdated",{state:page.$pristine});
});
```

And something like this in grid controller

```
$scope.on("formUpdated",function(args) {
    //args.state would have the state.
});
```

Note:`$rootScope` has to be injected into your controller like you inject `$scope`